# How can I get the properties of an imported bom

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a situation where I have two boms imported in the dependencyManagement section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>my.custom.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>my.custom.bom</artifactId>
                <version>${my.custom.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The my.custom.bom has the right version of spring-boot-dependencies in one of its properties that I'd like to always override the declared version. How can I get access to the properties of my.custom.bom? Gradle has this, but I was not able to find anything for Maven. If I get access to those properties of my.custom.bom then I can write a simple plugin that overrides the spring-boot-dependencies version with the one taken from the my.custom.bom. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your `my.custom.bom` already import the spring boot dependencies?

Comment: No, it doesn't but it might as well could. Would that help in this situation?

Comment: I would suggest to do so. That would solve the problem.. from my point of view...

Comment: Could you please give more details? How could I refer the spring-boot-dependencies bom in my application from the my.custom.bom? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same way you do here in the given post... ?

Comment: Well, if I do this then I loose the connection with my.custom.bom and that is something that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: The spring-boot-dependencies bom can be imported in your my.custom.bom and that's it...

Comment: I did import the spring-boot-dependencies in my.custom.bom and only imported the my.custom.bom in the dependencyManagement of my pom.xml but that does not work. Maybe I'm missing something???

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get access to the properties of my.custom.bom? Gradle has
> this, but I was not able to find anything for Maven.

Because that is not possible with maven. The only way you can access the properties is through inheritance (using the bom as a parent). Importing a pom (with "import") only imports its dependencies.

If you already have a parent you could use the '[Properties Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/index.html)' which can load maven properties from an external file.